# Updating documents with nested arrays based on conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB and have to work on a legacy project that I didn't create... and I'm struggling!

I need to *reset* some documents in one of my collections, based on a particular field value.  I have had some success with this so far, but some of the data I need to update is within nested arrays in that document, and I can't work that part out.

Below is an example of one document in the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1234567890"),
    "currentStatus" : "approved",
    "itemsInstalled" : [ 
        {
            "installDate" : ISODate("2017-04-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("1234567890"),
            "status" : "approved"
        }, 
        {
            "installDate" : ISODate("2017-04-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("0987654321"),
            "status" : "approved"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 5005,
    "approvalDate" : ISODate("2017-12-04T10:40:01.580Z"),
    "approvedBy" : "automatic"
}
```

I need to update **every** document in my collection where the `approvedBy` field is set to `automatic`, and leave the others untouched.

For the documents I am updating, I need to **remove** the `approvalDate` and `approvedBy` fields completely, change the `currentStatus` field to `action` and change **every** item in the `itemsInstalled` array to `pending`.  Everything else can stay as it is.

This is something I would persist with solving myself if I had more time.

Comment: This is straightforward in 3.6 version ( released couple of days ago ) with expressive updates. `db.collection_name.update(
    {"approvedBy": "automatic"},
    {$set: {"itemsInstalled.$[].status": "pending", currentStatus:"action"},
    $unset: {approvalDate: "",approvedBy: ""}}
  )`. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)  on usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, you can't update multiple array elements. Your best bet is probably to use `forEach`. You can accomplish what you want with something like this:

```
db.your_collection.find({
    approvedBy: "automatic"
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    for(var i = 0; i < doc.itemsInstalled.length; i++) {
        doc.itemsInstalled[i].status = "pending";
    }

    doc.currentStatus = "action";
    delete doc.approvedBy;
    delete doc.approvalDate;

    db.your_collection.update({_id: doc._id}, doc);
});
```

Using `forEach`, you can update all of the array elements at once. The downside is that you will be performing multiple update queries, so you should be careful about doing this on particularly large collections or as part of your application logic. Ideally this should be a one-time use scenario.